# Calling C++ Functions Inside an Assembly File

Tags: c++, assembly, visual-c++, x86, masm

This is my first time asking so I am going to do my best here, but I am having trouble on an assembly assignment in which I am given a .cpp file (below) and have to make an .asm file that contains a Multiply, Square, and Divide functions. The part I am having an issue with is that after the Square and Multiply functions are done, I have to call PrintResult to display the answer. For the Division, a successful divide returns a 1, and an unsuccessful one returns a 0 and call PrintResult to display the failure message. I am not allowed to edit his .cpp file, but I don't know how to successfully call PrintResult. I keep getting an error that says that there is an undefined symbol.

Here is the .cpp given:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

enum ResultCode { ShowSquare, ShowMultiply, ShowDivide, ShowRemainder, ShowDivideFailure };
enum SuccessCode { Failure, Success };

extern "C" SuccessCode Divide(long, long, long &, long &);
extern "C" long Multiply(long, long);
extern "C" void PrintResult(ResultCode, long);
extern "C" long Square(long);

void main()
{
    long Num1;
    long Num2;
    long Result;
    long Remainder;
    do
    {
        cout << "Enter Number to Square" << endl;
        cin >> Num1;
        Result = Square(Num1);
        cout << "Square is: " << Result << endl;
        cout << "Enter two numbers to multiply" << endl;
        cin >> Num1 >> Num2;
        Result = Multiply(Num1, Num2);
        cout << "Result of multiply is: " << Result << endl;
        cout << "Enter mumber to divide into then number to divide by" << endl;
        cin >> Num1 >> Num2;
        if (Divide(Num1, Num2, Result, Remainder) == Success)
            cout << "Result is " << Result << " and remainder is " << Remainder << endl;
        else
            cout << "Attempted division by zero";
    } while (Result > 0);
}

void PrintResult(ResultCode PrintCode, long Value)
{
    switch (PrintCode)
    {
    case ShowSquare:
        cout << "Display of square is: " << Value << endl;
        break;
    case ShowMultiply:
        cout << "Display of multiply is: " << Value << endl;
        break;
    case ShowDivide:
        cout << "Display of divide is " << Value << endl;
        break;
    case ShowRemainder:
        cout << "Display of remainder is " << Value << endl;
        break;
    case ShowDivideFailure:
        cout << "Display of Division by zero" << endl;
        break;
    default:
        cout << "Error in assembly routines" << endl;
    }
}
```

And here is what I have so far as an .asm file:

```
.386
.model flat
.code

public  _Square
public  _Multiply
public  _Divide


_Square     proc
            mov     eax, [esp + 4]
            imul    eax, eax
            push    eax

            push    eax
            push    0
            call    _PrintResult
            add     esp, 8

            pop     eax

            ret
_Square     endp

_Multiply   proc
            mov     eax, [esp + 8]
            mov     ebx, [esp + 4]
            imul    eax, ebx


            ret
_Multiply   endp

_Divide     proc


            ret
_Divide     endp


end
```

Currently my _Square function has what I pulled from another answer on here, but does not work. It tells me that PrintResult is undefined. I have my _Multiply written out but it does not have the call of course and I can write in the _Divide as soon as I know how formatting something like that would look..

Any help is more than appreciated!

Comment: Note: The javascript runners don't do C++.

Comment: Thank you so much, I could not figure out how to properly format. That way seemed the easiest to get it all separated and not cut lines.

Comment: You'll have to tell your MASM code that `_PrintResult` is an external label. Add this to the top of your assembler code `extern _PrintResult:near`

Comment: I typed that up quickly. Since it is a proc you may want to do it this way `extern _PrintResult:proc`

Comment: So for square, if I input 3 should that output "Display of square is: 9\t Square is: 9" ?

Comment: 3 squared is 3*3 and 3*3 = 9 so 9 should be the output.

Comment: I apologize, I should have asked my question better. I know it will square my number, but if ShowSquare is 0, shouldn't it output "Display of square is 0\t Square is: 9" ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `EXTERN` to tell the assembler about external things.

```
EXTERN _PrintResult
```

In this case, you may be better using `PROTO` and `INVOKE` 
[MSDN : proto/invoke](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/73407/using-proto-and-invoke-to-call-a-c-function-from-masm)

```
 PrintDisplay PROTO C arg1:SWORD, arg2:SWORD
```

followed by

```
 INVOKE PrintDisplay 0, eax
```

Comment: In MASM [EXTERN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7cycf5bc.aspx) requires a colon `:` and a type so I don't believe that `EXTERN _PrintResult` would assemble correctly without an error.